# expdp issue ORA-39001: invalid argument value

Tags: oracle, datapump, expdp

Originally, the script was like:

```
C:\Windows\system32>expdp anna/12356@inst2
 PARFILE=E:\expdp\db001\_db001.par

Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Sep 3 22:59:30 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP and Data Mining options

ORA-31626: job does not exist 
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 for user 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1002 ORA-39001: invalid argument value
```

Then I searched online and read all the similar cases, but none of them are exactly the same as my case. I get directory, user privileges and all other things ready, but it still showing the error.

Then I tried to narrow down the range of the root cause. When I enter the script as following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>expdp anna/12356@inst2
```

The error was like following the picture:

[image]

Seems like the expdp utility can not recognized the username/pwd "anna/12356"
Any one know how does this come from and how to solve it?

Comment: does it work when you try it as sys (replace sys with sys-pw)? `expdp \"SYS/sys AS SYSDBA\"`

Comment: I tried sys, system and some other users, and none of them worked. the errors were the same. usually we will get [ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 for user "blablabla"], but for my case, there were nothing after "user". I thought maybe the expdp utility got corrupted and i run both "utlrp.sql" and "catclust.sql", but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing:

1. run **catalog.sql** (re-creates all the data dictionary views)
2. run **catproc.sql**
3. run **utlrp.sql**